# Affecting variable through eval or similar

Tags: r, eval

I know that if i have the name of a variable stored like `a = "var.name"`, i can call this `var.name` by doing `eval(as.symbol(a))` or `get(a)`, but i wanted to not only call a variable, but also make changes to it. Example:

```
names = c("X1","X2")
for(i in names){
    assign(i, cbind(replicate(2,rnorm(3))) #Just creating a 3x2 matrix with dummy data
    ###
```

At ### i'd like to make a change to the variables, specifically change its column names to "a" and "b".

I tried `colnames(get(i)) = c("a","b")`, or `colnames(eval(as.symbol(i))) = c("a","b")`, but they return errors like `could not find function "eval<-"`

Comment: Not really answering your exact question, but I have almost always found it the case that I am better off working in a `list()` than trying to do things like this. Basically you can do the same thing, but store the object (matrix, data frame, whatever) in the list instead of in the global environment.

Comment: @Adam you're right, there was no need do use the method i was using and what you said solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to create the matrix in the first step, and name and assign to a new name in the second step.

```
names = c("X1","X2")
for(i in names){
  x <- cbind(replicate(2,rnorm(3))) 
  assign(i, provideDimnames(x))
}   

#--------------
> X1
            A          B
A -0.59174062  1.8527780
B -0.53088643 -3.2713544
C -0.09330006 -0.5977568
```

---

Another option would be to assign the dimnames at the time of creation of the matrix.

```
for (i in names) {
  x <- matrix(replicate(2, rnorm(3)),
              ncol = 2,
              dimnames = list(a = c(LETTERS[1:3]), b = c(LETTERS[1:2])))
  
  assign(i, x)
}

#-------------------
> X1

   b
a            A           B
  A -0.2313692 -0.93161762
  B -0.9666849  0.06164904
  C  1.5614446 -0.09391062
```